# Memory does not go down when I press GoBack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

When GoBack I call function Dispose() in

```
 private void Dispose()
    {


        ImageBrush brushRoot = LayoutRoot.Background as ImageBrush;
        if (brushRoot != null)
        {
            ((BitmapImage)brushRoot.ImageSource).UriSource = null;
            brushRoot.ImageSource = null;
            LayoutRoot.Background = null;
        }

        gridHeader_hotNews.Children.Clear();
        gridHeader_hotNews = null;

        if (grid_Two.Background as ImageBrush != null)
        {
            ((BitmapImage)(grid_Two.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource).UriSource = null;
            (grid_Two.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource = null;
            grid_Two.Background = null;
        }
        if (btn_Two.Background as ImageBrush != null)
        {
            ((BitmapImage)(btn_Two.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource).UriSource = null;
            (btn_Two.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource = null;
            btn_Two.Click -= new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Two_Click);
            btn_Two.Background = null;
        }
        btn_Two = null;
        grid_Two.Children.Clear();
        grid_Two = null;

        grid_Content.Children.Clear();
        grid_Content = null;

        if (grid_footer.Background as ImageBrush != null)
        {
            ((BitmapImage)(grid_footer.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource).UriSource = null;
            (grid_footer.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource = null;
            grid_footer.Background = null;
        }
        if (btnspeaker.Background as ImageBrush != null)
        {
            ((BitmapImage)(btnspeaker.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource).UriSource = null;
            (btnspeaker.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource = null;
            btnspeaker.Background = null;
        }
        btnspeaker = null;

        grid_footer.Children.Clear();
        grid_footer = null;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();
        LayoutRoot = null;
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

but is still uses 3 to 5 MB. How do I recover the original memory when I call the GoBack event?

Please help me, I want memory released when back I Page or I Dispose of the Object.

Comment: this code will not clear all objects with the GC as you still hold a lot of references. But normaly this should be no problem - the GC will do it's work just fine - may I ask why you need to do something like this?

Comment: @thong Invoking `GC` doesn't force it to begin directly

Comment: @Carsten Konig ! Thank for reply question , i want replease memory when back Page , but memory decreased very little. How to manage memory , i release object Referent , array .... but still not solved?

Comment: At first glance, the only thing you do in there that is actually helpful to garbage collection is when you unsubscribe to the Click event. You can remove all the rest.

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collector only runs when it is required to run, so it won't necessarily run as soon as you run Dispose.

You can force the GC to collect by calling GC.Collect();  but this will probably have an effect on your apps performance.  This is because when the GC runs it stops all executing threads in your application and checks each object in the heap to see if it is still referenced or in use.  While the garbage collector is fast there will be an overhead to calling the GC repeatedly.

As the other people commenting have said, it's best to let the GC manage itself.